# php - Facebook Api - Get Fan Page Posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, posts, facebook-page

I am trying to get user's fan page post using the following code, but it's give me warning

`Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/782176371798916/posts): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`

```
$page_posts = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/posts');
$pageposts = json_decode($page_posts);
foreach ($pageposts["data"] as $fppost) {
echo $fppost['message'];
}
```

SO, how is the correct way to get user's fan page post?

Comment: I don't see the `access_token=CAAAA......`, accessing the calls `/posts` or `/feed` requires a valid `access_token`, **the ERROR says it all**

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is by using the following code:

```
$pageposts = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/posts', 'GET');
foreach ($pageposts["data"] as $fppost) {
echo $fppost['message'];
}
```

Comment: He's using `file_get_contents` not the php sdk, your answer is far of his method

Comment: I am answering this question: `SO, how is the correct way to get user's fan page post?`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't send the `access_token` parameter, just add it and it should work like charm:

```
$page_id = 'smashmag'; // Page ID or username

$token = '553435274702353|OaJc7d2WCoDv83AaR4JchNA_Jgw'; // Valid access token, I used app token here but you might want to use a user token .. up to you

$page_posts = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/posts?fields=message&access_token='.$token); // > fields=message < since you want to get only 'message' property (make your call faster in milliseconds) you can remove it

$pageposts = json_decode($page_posts); 

foreach ($pageposts->data as $fppost) {

             if (property_exists($fppost, 'message')) { // Some posts doesn't have message property (like photos set posts), errors-free ;)
                 print $fppost->message.'</br>';
             }
}
```